# Flutter return future enum

Tags: flutter, return, future

I try to return a future list enum that I want to use in the UI. But I can't return correct type from my parse function. I want the functions to be able to work together.

The InstalledOption is an Emun if that is useful.

```
enum InstalledOption { option1, option2 }



    Future<List<InstalledOption>> fetchInstalledOption() async {
        //Async bluetooth read...
      var rawOptions = await characteristic?.read();

      return parseInstalledOptions(rawOptions);
    });
    return parseInstalledOptions([0]);
  }

  List<InstalledOption> parseInstalledOptions(List<int> options) {
    for (int i = 0; i < (options.length) / 2; i++) {
      //Looping and setting values
    }

    List<InstalledOption> installedOptions = [];
    for (var value in installedOptionsValues) {
      //Looping and setting values
    }
    return installedOptions;
  }
```

**On line** `return parseInstalledOptions(rawOptions);` **I get the error:** The return type 'List' isn't a 'Future', as required by the closure's context.

Comment: Please post an example that can reproduce your problem.  You've omitted the relevant code and are showing code with a `return` statement outside of a function.

Comment: Did you try to add async after the function parseInstalledOptions (...) async { ... }